# Sums of four series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Are the following  series convergent?  If yes, where will they converge?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{\sin{e^n}} {n}}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left({\frac{\sin{e^n}} {n}}\right)^2$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{\arctan{e^n}} {n}}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{\cos{e^n}} {n}}$$

Comment: what do you mean where?  this series are either divergent or spit out a real number...

Comment: @yoyo thanks. where means to what value they converge if they

Answer (score 3):

I don't think 1) and 4) are known.  They depend on how close $2 e^n/\pi$ is to even and odd integers.  These are hard questions. 2) and 3) are easy, though.

Comment: For 1) and 4), would one be prone to guess that they converge because the numerator will be random in [-1,1]?  Of course, that is no help in determining the limit.

Comment: WolframAlpha says that (1) converges to about 1.19261 and that (2) converges to -1.27659.

Comment: @Zach Langley:WolframAlpha most probably uses numerical evaluation of the sum with some sort of extrapolation (which "improves" convergence). There is no way you can determine numerically whether such a sum converges or diverges.

Comment: For an interesting one along these lines: show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sin((\pi/2) \phi^n)/n$ diverges, where $\phi = (1+\sqrt{5})/2$.

Answer (score 2):

1) and 4) are (basically) the same and i dont know...might need to bound partial sums $\sum\sin e^n$ to use some of the basic convergence tests.  for 2) compare with $\sum 1/n^2$.  for 3) $\arctan x\to\pi/2$ as $x\to\infty$, so compare to $\sum 1/n$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to apply *Dirichlet's test*, but you need to bound the sums $\sum_{n=1}^N \sin e^n$.